# Replace multiple variables in R Sql Query

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I have a query similar like the one below where I need to use multiple string of characters to replace in a single query.

I am not too sure how to make sure a and b are passed into the %s in the query.

I am getting the error 'unused arguments (b)'

```
   a
 [1] "A10000001" "C10000002" "10000003"
 [4] "10000004" "D10000005" "10000006"
 


  b
 [1] "A100000011" "B100000021" "100000031"
 [4] "10000004" "10000005" "10000006"

expr1 <- sprintf("select
 FSAS.a_id,
 FSAS.grade,
 FSAS.score,
 FSAS.placement,
 FSAS.start,
 FSAS.completion 
 FROM db.Fact AS FSAS
 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT FB.end , FB.ids, FB.place FROM FB where FB.ids in (%s))
 ON FB.end = FSAS.start
 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT FAB.a, FAB.ids FROM FAB WHERE FAB.ids in (%s))
 ON FAB.a = FB.place", toString(sQuote(a, b, q = FALSE), collapse=", "))

sqlQuery(con, expr1)
```

Any advice please?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sQuote` only takes one vector as an argument. You can't give it `a` and `b` at the same time as separate arguments.  And `collapse` is an argument for `paste`, not for `toString`. And `sprintf` will want separate arguments for each `%s`. I think you want

```
qry = "select
 FSAS.a_id,
 FSAS.grade,
 FSAS.score,
 FSAS.placement,
 FSAS.start,
 FSAS.completion 
 FROM db.Fact AS FSAS
 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT FB.end , FB.ids, FB.place FROM FB where FB.ids in (%s))
 ON FB.end = FSAS.start
 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT FAB.a, FAB.ids FROM FAB WHERE FAB.ids in (%s))
 ON FAB.a = FB.place"

expr1 = sprintf(
  qry,
  toString(sQuote(a, q = FALSE)),
  toString(sQuote(b, q = FALSE))
)
```

Comment: I cannot believe I spend hours on this. Thank you so much!!! Also thank you for the explaination on how to use sQuote, paste, collapse and etc. Appreciate it!!!